# Angular Yahoo Weather API

Tags: javascript, angular, api, yahoo, weather

I have a problem with the Yahoo Weather API. How should I make a request to get data from the Yahoo Weather API?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWeatherForecast(city: string): Observable<any> {
   const url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select wind from 
   weather.forecast where woeid=2460286';
   return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual code instead of a picture. Thank you

Comment: You're currently getting a 404, possibly because of spaces in the URL. Can you try using `encodeURI` on that url, and using the encoded URL instaed? Also, when I hit that URL, I'm getting XML back, which may cause you issues, as HttpClient will try to parse the results as JSON by default

Comment: I have changed url for https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22greenland%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys from docs, but result is same.

Comment: If you check in your browser's developer tools network panel, is it trying to connect to the correct URL? That URL seems to work fine for me? Failing that, can you please create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? Thanks

Comment: It seems to be working in [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmujks?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)?

Comment: You are right. I have In-memory-web-api in app. I think it is a problem.

Comment: user184994 thank so much. In-memory-web-api has blocked my requests. I had to set Config.passThruUnknownUrl = true.

Answer (score 0):

Working example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdbrrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Your only problem was that you forgot to add: **&format=json** to your url string.

The returned data was in **XML** format by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example, but I hope it helps you. I'll use a library called `axios` right here:

```js
const url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='Sunderland') and u='c'&format=json";
  
    const getWeatherData = () => {
         axios.get(url)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data.query.results.channel.item.condition))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.data))
    }
    
    getWeatherData();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.12.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```